# List of all in-built events in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the nodejs docs, i came across multiple event names for process.stdin like, 'readable', 'data', 'end' etc.

For example:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write(`data: ${chunk}`);
  }
});
```

I found this on https://nodejs.org/api/process.html.

Where can i find the list of all built-in event names with some explanation and when it is fired ?

Comment: in the rest of the documentation

Comment: This question is incomplete. All built-in events of which built-in module? If you mean all built-in events of node.js itself then it's easy: there are zero built-in events for node.js itself. Now, for all the built-in events of the process module read the documentation of process. For all the built-in events of I/O streams read the documentation of stream. This even works for external libraries. For all built-in event of socket.io (not a built-in node module) read the documentation of socket.io

Answer (score 2):

The event documentation is spread throughout the node.js documentation. For example, https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

If you want to look for specifically in a particular module for example, `http` module, https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest
You can also take a look above where `http` has its own set of events.

Comment: Hi Ankita, better use comment section for suggesting anything to OP. *Thanks*